# Struct data and malloc; not receiving the data waited

Tags: c, memory, struct, memory-management, malloc

I'm stuck on how to correct implement date inside a struct that been declared with malloc.

I have these two structs:

```
typedef struct {
int idWork;
float area;
//char tarifa[MAX_TARIFA_LENG];
int tarifa;
} tWorkspace;

typedef struct{
tPartner *socis;
tWorkspace workP[50];
tContract *contract;
int numSocis;
int numWork;
int numContract;
} tCoworking;
```

Then, I have this function which I didn't coded right

```
tCoworking* new_partner(tCoworking *a, int partnerId, char *nam, int descom){
bool exist = false;

a->socis=(tPartner*)malloc(sizeof(tPartner*));

printf("ID %d\n", partnerId);

//CHECK IF PARTNERID EXISTS IN THE LIST
if(a->numSocis != 0){
    for(int i=0; i<a->numSocis; i++){
        if(a->socis[i].id == partnerId){
            exist = true;
            printf("\nERROR: Partner %d is already in the list of partners\n",partnerId);
        }
    }
}
if(exist != true){
    //Check if there's no socis
    if(a->numSocis != 0){
        a->socis[a->numSocis].id = partnerId;
        strcpy(a->socis[a->numSocis].name, nam);
        a->socis[a->numSocis].descompte = descom;
        a->numSocis = a->numSocis+1;
    }else{
        a->socis[0].id = partnerId;
        strcpy(a->socis[0].name, nam);
        a->socis[0].descompte = descom;
        a->numSocis = 1;
    }
}
return a;
}
```

In main, I have:

```
tCoworking c;
```

and this is how I call the function with the data:

```
new_partner (&c, 11, "Anwar Sherman", 10);
```

What happens is that when I call it for the first time `a->socis[0].id` gives me the **ID 11**, which is correct.

But when I call it again `new_partner (&c, 16, "Isa Warner", 20);` the index **0** lose the previous data  and in index **1** writes the data correctly.

I mean, on second call of function, the struct gives me this:

**index 0** = **110**

**index 1** = **16**

If I keep calling the function, the previous data is set **0** and the data I pass it "saves"

Why do I use malloc ? I don't know the exact number of users that I will get, so I'm trying to work with Dynamic Memory Allocation and Dynamic Structures

Sorry for bad english and bad explanation, I tried my best.

Thanks.

EDIT

Changed to `a->socis=(tPartner*)malloc(sizeof(tPartner))`

When I call for the third time my function with different data, it looks like this:

```
index 0 = 1852989783
index 1 = 0
index 2 = 24
```

Function calls with data are:

```
  new_partner (&c, 11, "Anwar Sherman", 10);
  new_partner (&c, 16, "Isa Warner", 20);
  new_partner (&c, 24, "Reagan Sawyer", 8);
```

More examples:

```
new_partner (&c, 11, "Anwar Sherman", 10);
new_partner (&c, 16, "Isa Warner", 20);
new_partner (&c, 24, "Reagan Sawyer", 8);
new_partner (&c, 67, "Hashir Lloyd", 10);
```

What I get:

```
index 0 = 0
index 1 = 1394634337
index 3 = 0
index 4 = 67
```

Comment: `malloc(sizeof(tPartner*));` should be `malloc(sizeof(tPartner))`.  You need enough space to hold the entire `tPartner` object, but you only allocated enough space to store a pointer.  General rule of thumb: the type argument to `sizeof` inside `malloc` should have one less `*` than the type of the pointer to which the result is being assigned.

Comment: Alternatively, dereference the pointer being assigned instead of trying to rewrite the type: `ptr = malloc(sizeof(*ptr))`.

Comment: Change made. Now when I call for the second time my function, the index 0 is 0, before it was 110. Now it not saving anything. I'm edting my question

Comment: Oh, you are overwriting `a->socis` with every call to the function, with a pointer to an array that only contains enough space for one `tPartner`.  It seems like you want this to point to an array containing all the previous `tPartners`, and so you will need to use `realloc` to expand it instead of overwriting it.

Comment: @NateEldredge This worked, If you want add this is a answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing this:

```
a->socis = malloc(sizeof(tPartner*));
```

to this:

```
a->socis = malloc(sizeof(tPartner));
```

since you want to add an object of type `tPartner`. That requires allocating memory for an object of that size, and not of its pointer, as you do in your code.

---

PS: Unrelated to your issue: [Do I cast the result of malloc?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc) No.

Comment: Change made.
Now when I call for the second time my function, the index **0** is ```0```, before it was ```110```. Now it not saving anything. I'm edting my question